# Size not being displayed on productdetails page

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-serializer

I am doing CRUD using serializers and foreign keys and I have made a product details page which shows the details of the product that I have clicked. The problem is that the Size(SM,M,L,XL,XXL) itself isn't coming but the id is coming as shown below
[image: as shown in the image, the id or number is getting displayed instead of the size itself]
below is the 'productdetails' function

```
<tr>
    <td>{{data.id}}</td>
    <td>{{data.title}}</td>
    <td>{{data.price}}</td>
    <td>{{data.sku_number}}</td>
    <td>{{data.product_details}}</td>
    <td>{{data.size}}</td>
    <td>{{data.quantity}}</td>
    <td><img src="{{data.image}}" alt="product image" width="400" height="400"></td>
</tr>
```

productdetails function

```
def productdetails(request,id):
    prod = Products.objects.get(id=id)
    product = POLLSerializer(prod)
    return render(request,'polls/productdetails.html',{'data':product.data})
```

model

```
class Products(models.Model):
    categories = models.ForeignKey(Categories,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sub_categories = models.ForeignKey(SUBCategories,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    color = models.ForeignKey(Colors,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    size = models.ForeignKey(Size,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'media/',width_field=None,height_field=None,null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    sku_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    product_details = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    isactive = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

serializer

```
class POLLSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Products
        fields = "__all__"
```

size model and serializer

```
class Size(models.Model):
    size_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    size_description = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    isactive = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.size_name

class SizeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Size
        fields = "__all__"
```

Comment: Share the `POLLSerializer`. Why do you use a serialzer by the way for simple rendering?

Comment: Hi Willem,I have added the serializer.I am tasked to use a serializer instead of forms

Comment: but you don't need forms as well: since you are rendering the object, you can simply pass it to the context. Please also add the `Size` model.

Comment: Hi Willem, I have added the model and the serializer of Size model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this in ypur view.py

```
def productdetails(request,id):
   prod = Products.objects.get(id=id)
   product = POLLSerializer(prod)
   return render(request,'polls/productdetails.html',{'data':prod.data})
```

Comment: Hi omar it worked,only correction is that there should be only be prod and not prod.data

Comment: @AmeyaPotdar: using the `POLLSeriializer` here is useless. It does not do anything, so the `product = ...` line should be removed.